# Prevent multicols* from creating a new page

Tags: multicol

Is there a way to prevent a multicols* section from creating a new page? I'd like to make two small columns  with different heights  but I do not want to create a new page. Here is some code to show what I'm doing:

```
\begin{multicols*}{2}

\section{Hello}

\paragraph{The quick brown fox.}

\columnbreak

\section{World}

\paragraph{The quick brown fox.}

\end{multicols*}
```

Using this causes all content after the multicols* section to be moved to a new page. Is there any way to prevent this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: please show an example that people can run to see the problem. Note that `\paragraph` is a 4th level section heading, it should follow `\subsection` not `\section` and should have some following text. Page breaking would normally be suppressed after a heading.

Comment: ...i,e, if for some peculiar reason you wanted to use your code as is, simply adding something visible or invisible after the last paragraph solve the problem, e.g.:   `...fox.} Whatever`  or  `...fox.} \hspace{0pt}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution, using normal `multicols` and adding `\raggedcolumns` achieves what I was looking for.

```
\begin{multicols}{2}
\raggedcolumns

\section{Hello}

\paragraph{The quick brown fox.}

\columnbreak

\section{World}

\paragraph{The quick brown fox.}

\end{multicols}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `multicols*` environents semantic is that it uses *all* of the remaining galley space to form the columns and then fills them with material one after another. Thus you are by definition at the end of the page when it finishes even if your material is not even enough to fill the first column.

If you instead want a short passage of several columns in the middle of a page then you need to use `multicol`.  Now that balances the column material, but there are several parameters that you can use to influence how that balancing happens:

- you can set the `unbalance` to a positive value. That makes all columns that number of lines longer than normal balancing would do. (This is an per env setting)
- you can also experience with `minrows` counter which forces a minimal number of lines in the first column.